# string to jQuery element different in IE and Firefox/Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, morris.js

I have a Morris Area Chart and I'm changing the labels colors on mouse over a point with the function `hoverCallback`:

```js
var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'gray', 'darkorange', 'darkviolet'];

Morris.Area({
  element: 'chart',
  data: [
    { y: '2006', a: 100, b: 90 },
    { y: '2007', a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { y: '2008', a: 50,  b: 40 },
    { y: '2009', a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { y: '2010', a: 50,  b: 40 },
    { y: '2011', a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { y: '2012', a: 100, b: 90 }
  ],
  xkey: 'y',
  ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
  labels: ['Series A', 'Series B'],
  lineColors: colors,
  fillOpacity: 0.4,
  hoverCallback: function(index, options, content, row) {
    var currentDiv = "";
    var finalContent = $("<div/>").addClass("bold");
    var cpt = 0;

    $(content).each(function() {
      currentDiv = $(this);
      if ($(this).hasClass("morris-hover-point")) {
        if (cpt == colors.length - 1) {
          cpt = 0;
        }
        $(currentDiv).css("color", colors[cpt]);
        cpt++;
      }
      $(finalContent).append(currentDiv);
    });

    return finalContent;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="chart"></div>
```

But I'm having different behaviour between IE and Firefox/Chrome. So I'm unable to use the jQuery `each` iterator:

```
$(content).each(function() { ... });
```

The problem is that when I'm displaying the `content` parameter of the `hoverCallback` function in the console, the first `div` is not closed in IE:

```
"<div class='morris-hover-row-label'>2008
 <div class='morris-hover-point' style='color: #689bc3'>
 Series A:
 50
 </div>
 <div class='morris-hover-point' style='color: #689bc3'>
 Series B:
 40
 </div>"
```

But in Firefox/Chrome, it's correctly closed:

```
"<div class='morris-hover-row-label'>2008</div>
 <div class='morris-hover-point' style='color: #689bc3'>
 Series A:
 50
 </div>
 <div class='morris-hover-point' style='color: #689bc3'>
 Series B:
 40
 </div>"
```

So when the jQuery element `$(content)` is created in IE, it generates a parent `div` with class `morris-hover-row-label` with the others `div` as child and in Firefox/Chrome it generates all `div` at the same level.

So, if you run the code snippet, it should render the labels as red and blue in Firefox/Chrome and as default colors in IE.

**UPDATE**

Well, it's working in IE when running inside the code snippet. But not when I'm running the same code for example with Visual Studio in IE.

Differences Firefox/IE:

[image: Differences Firefox/IE]

Why this difference? Does it comes from Morris.js or a different behavior from the browser ?

Comment: What exactly is the difference? What exactly is being passing to `$()`? Narrow down your problem to just the content being passed to `$()`.

Comment: I found the source of the problem: a `div` in not correctly closed with IE but I don't know why. See my edit @KevinB

Comment: Looks like a problem with whatever `Morris.Area` is.